# Grafana + Prometheus Pie Chart Group by

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-templating

I am trying to build a pie chart using `Grafana` & `Prometheus` using Group by

In Grafana's panel

- Query A: success
- Query B: failure

If there is only single prometheus job, then it's perfect, it will have 2 parts:

- success job 1
- failure job 1

But this wouldn't work since there are multiple `job`s.

E.g. there are 3 jobs, so the 1 pie chart created has 6 parts:

- success job 1
- success job 2
- success job 3
- failure job 1
- failure job 2
- failure job 3

**What I want is 3 pie charts, group by `job`, each with success and failure**. So I change the queries:

- Query A: `sum by (job) (success)`
- Query B: `sum by (job) (failure)`

Still it's a single pie chart with 6 parts.

Thanks.